# TypeError: factory is not a function in Angular 4.1.3

Tags: angular

I've a strange error message in an Angular application and I can´t figure out what's happening.

```
ERROR TypeError: factory is not a function
    at resolveViewDefinition (eval at 17 (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:214:1), <anonymous>:9160:17)
    at createViewNodes (eval at 17 (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:214:1), <anonymous>:12192:56)
    at callViewAction (eval at 17 (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:214:1), <anonymous>:12601:13)
```

I started removing code from the app and I ended up with something extremely simple, so no routing, no components other than app.component, and then it became even more strange.

If I have this in my app.component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
        <div>{{ nav[0].name }}</div>
        <div>{{ nav[1].name }}</div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  nav = [
    {
      link: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      exact: true
    },
    {
      link: '/two',
      name: 'Two',
      exact: true
    }
  ];

}
```

Then it works fine, but if I have this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      It works
        <div>{{ nav[0].name }}</div>
        <div>{{ nav[1].name }}</div>
        <div *ngFor="let item of nav">
          {{ item.name }}
        </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  nav = [
    {
      link: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      exact: true
    },
    {
      link: '/two',
      name: 'Two',
      exact: true
    }
  ];

}
```

then I get the error from above. So it's just adding the *ngFor that everything breaks apart.

In my module I have this

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    TwoComponent
  ]
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So, I'm not using routing anymore and I'm importing CommonModule, what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you reproduce it somewhere in live example? You have something wrong with your configuration https://plnkr.co/edit/WacfODaOJBFH52wWhJfE?p=preview

Comment: Ok, there was something in my libraries that was breaking everything down. I just copied the yarn.lock from a previous build and it worked fine. The difference is Angular 4.1.1 to 4.1.3, but I think there has to be something else.